# Stirling numbers, binomial coefficients

Tags: discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

Could you help me prove the following:

$$\left\{n\atop k\right\} = \frac{1}{k!} \cdot \sum^{k}_{j=0} {k\choose j} \cdot j^{n} \cdot (-1)^{k-j}$$

It looks very scary to me. I've looked for it in Graham, Knuth, Patashnik's "Concrete Mathematics", but I didn't find it. All I know about Stirling numbers is that we can use them as coefficients in $x^{(n)(n-1)...(n-k+1)}$ in the sum of $ x^k, \ 0 \le k \le n$

or in $x^n$ when we want to express it as a sum of $x^{(n)(n-1)...(n-k+1)}$. But I don't think this would help me in any way.

I think we divide the sum on the left hand side by $k!$ because when we choose subsets order doesn't matter. Then maybe ${k\choose j}$ means that we choose $j$ elements to our $k$ -element subset and we can choose them in $j^n$ (?) ways and $(-1)^{k-j}$ must mean inclusion\exclusion principle.

Please, help.

Comment: If you have access to Knuth's *Fundamental algorithms*, Stirling numbers are extensively discussed there. Also, have you read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number)?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. Could you send me a link?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Explicit_formula) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_difference#Higher-order_differences).

Comment: *Fundamental algorithms* is not online, as far as I know. Any halfway decent university library ought to have it.

Comment: It’s [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Art-Computer-Programming-Fundamental-Algorithms/dp/0201896834).

Comment: The identity is (6.19) in *Concrete Mathematics*, though I don’t think that it’s proved in the text.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't there any simpler, combinatorial proof of this identity? And as for "Concrete Mathematics", this identity is indeed (6.19), but it's not proven anywhere in the text.

Comment: You might want to specify in the post what you mean by Stirling number. This will help anyone who wants to write out a proof. The reason is that the Inclusion/Exclusion formula you give is an immediate consequence of one definition of Stirling number. And another standard definition is precisely with that formula!

Comment: By Stirling number I understand the number of partitions of a n-element set into k non-empty k-element sets.

Comment: And that’s the definition that I used for my answer.

Comment: Yes, I see that now :) Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\left\{n\atop k\right\}$ is the number of ways of putting $n$ distinguishable objects into exactly $k$ indistinguishable boxes. If we give the boxes identities, they can be permuted in $k!$ ways, so $\sum_{j\ge 0}\binom{k}jj^n(-1)^{k-j}$ ought to be the number of ways of putting $n$ distinguishable objects into $k$ distinguishable boxes subject to the condition that no box be empty. In other words, it should be the number of surjections from $[n]$ to $[k]$, and indeed it is, by a straightfoward inclusion-exclusion argument.