# Arrangements of sets of k positions in a n-competitors race

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, permutations, combinations

Let $E(n)$ be the set of all possible **ending arrangements** of a race of $n$ **competitors**.

Obviously, because it's a race, each one of the $n$ competitors wants to win.
Hence, the order of the arrangements **does** matter.
Let us also say that if two competitors end with the same result of time, they win the same spot.

For example, $E(3)$ contains the following sets of arrangements:

${(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,2,1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3), (1,3,2), (2,1,1), (2,1,2),(2,1,3), (2,2,1), (2,3,1), (3,1,2), (3,2,1)}.$

Needless to say, for example, that the arrangement $(1,3,3)$ is invalid, because the two competitors that **supposedly** ended in the third place, **actually** ended in the second place. So the above arrangement **"transfers"** to $(1,2,2)$.

Define $k$ to be the number of **distinct** **positions** of the competitors in a subset of $E(n)$. 
We have for example:

$(1,1,1)\Rightarrow k = 1$

$(1,2,1)\Rightarrow k = 2$

$(1,2,3,2)\Rightarrow k = 3$

$(1,2,1,5,4,4,3)\Rightarrow k = 5$

**Finally**, let $M(n,k)$ be the **number of subsets** of $E(n)$ in which the competitors ended in **exactly** $k$ distinct positions.

We get, for example, $M(3,3) = M(3,2) = 6$ and $M(3,1) = 1$.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Thus far is the question

It's a problem I came up with solely by myself. After some time of thought I came up with the following recursive formula for $|E(n)|$: 
**(Don't continue reading if you want to derive a formula yourself!)**

$$|E(n)| = \sum_{l=1}^n\binom{n}{l}\cdot |E(n-l)| \quad\text{where}\quad |E(0)| = 1$$

The logic behind this recurrence relation is that $l$ symbolizes how many "first" spots we have. For each $l$, the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{l}$ symbolizes in how many ways we can pick $l$ first-placers out of the $n$ competitors. Once we have chosen them, we to need to figure out in how many ways we can arrange the $n-l$ competitors we have left, which is just $|E(n-l)|$.
I get the following:

$|E(3)| = 13$

$|E(5)| = 541$

$|E(10)| = 102247563$

$|E(100)|$ mod $1$ $000$ $000$ $007 = 619182829$ $\rightarrow$ 20 ms.

And $|E(1000)|$ mod $1$ $000$ $000$ $007 = 581423957$ $\rightarrow$ 39 sec.

I figured out that $|E(n)|$ can also be visualized as the number of sets to which the following applies:

For every $i = 1, 2, 3 ... n$, every $i$-tuple subset of the original set has GCD (greatest common divisor) of all of its elements equal to 1.
But I'm not 100% sure about this because I was not able to compute this approach for large $n$.
However, even with precalculating factorials and memoizing the $E(n)$'s, the calculating times for higher $n$'s grow very fast.
Is anyone capable of verifying the above formula and values?
Can anyone derive a better, faster formula? Perhaps with generating functions?

As for $M(n,k)$.. I'm totally clueless. I absolutely have no idea how to calculate it, and therefore I couldn't post any meaningful data points. 
Perhaps it's $P(n,k) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$.
Can anyone figure out a formula for $M(n,k)$?

I have no idea which function is harder to compute, either $E(n)$ or $M(n,k)$, but helping me with either of them will be very much appreciable.

I want the solutions to be generic as well as work efficiently even for large $n$'s. Exhaustive search is not what I'm looking for, unfortunately. 
What I am looking for is solutions based purely on combinatorial approach and efficient formulas.

I hope I was clear enough with the wording and what I ask for throughout my post. By the way, I can program using Java. I also know Mathematica pretty decently :) .

Thanks a lot in advance,

Matan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers $|E_n|$ are the [*Fubini* (or *ordered Bell*) numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number), [OEIS A000670](http://oeis.org/A000670). The OEIS entry has numerous alternative descriptions and references. Among the formulas are

$$|E_n|=\sum_{k=1}^nk!{n\brace k}=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(k-1)^n}{2^k}$$

and your recurrence

$$|E_n|=\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}k|E_{n-k}|$$

with initial condition $|E_0|=1$. It’s also noted that $|E_n|$ is asymptotic to $\dfrac{n!}2(\log_2e)^{n+1}$. This is approximately $12.99629$ for $n=3$, $541.00152$ for $n=5$, and $102,247,563.0053$ for $n=10$; the corresponding values of $|E_n|$ are $13$, $541$, and $102,247,563$, so it appears to be a very good approximation.

There is a nice exponential generating function,

$$g(x)=\frac1{2-e^x}\;.$$

$M(n,k)$ is the number of surjections from $[n]$ to $[k]$. You can find a recurrence for it in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138899/number-of-surjections-from-one-set-to-another) and its answers. My answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296142/stirling-numbers-binomial-coefficients) sketches the argument that

$$M(n,k)=\sum_{j\ge 0}\binom{k}jj^n(-1)^{k-j}=k!{n\brace k}\;.$$

($n\brace k$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).)

Comment: Amazing. Simply amazing.. I have no idea how did you know all of this. How did you? Wow.. I am absolutely amazed. My honest appreciation and admiration to you sir. I wish I will sometime be as smart. @Brian

Comment: @Matan: Partly experience, and partly knowing where to look for more information – which also comes from experience. Glad to help!

Comment: Hey I just tried the formula u gave: $\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{(k-1)^n}{2^k}$ But it doesn't give me the correct results. Maybe I didn't understand it properly.. But can you check it again or explain? I used the sum from k=1 to k=n. @Brian

Comment: @Matan: I simply quoted it, so I’m taking it on faith. Note that it’s an infinite series. I just evaluated the partial sum up to $k=13$ for $n=3$ and got about $12.6538$, so I can believe that it converges to the correct $13$. To use it in any practical way, though, you’d have to work out how many terms you have to include to get within $1$, say, of the correct value.

Comment: Great, I didn't notice it's an infinite series. Thanks a lot again! @Brian

Comment: @Matan: You’re welcome. If I have some time later, I’ll see if I can come up with an estimate for how many terms are needed.

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, let $[n] = \{1, 2, 3, \ldots, n\}$

Then M(n,k) is the number of onto functions $f:[n]\to[k]$.

I think that's

$\binom k k k^n - \binom{k}{k-1}(k-1)^n + \binom{k}{k-2}(k-2)^n + \cdots \pm \binom{k}{1}1^n$